# Determine the existing properties in a iframe element

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe

The following script:

```
function getIframe(id) {
   var iframe=null;
   for (var i = window.frames.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if(window.frames[i].frameElement.id==id){iframe=window.frames[i];break;}
   }
   return iframe;
}

console.log('iframe:',iframe);
console.log('keys',Object.keys(iframe));
console.log('iframe["width"]',iframe["width"]);
```

produces the following results:

```
iframe: Window ~.php?task=get_image&dummy=1435083899977
keys ["close", "stop", "focus", "blur", "open", "alert", "confirm", "prompt", "print", "showModalDialog", "postMessage", "captureEvents", "releaseEvents", "getSelection", "getComputedStyle", "matchMedia", "moveTo", "moveBy", "resizeTo", "resizeBy", "scroll", "scrollTo", "scrollBy", "requestAnimationFrame", "cancelAnimationFrame", "getDefaultComputedStyle", "mozRequestAnimationFrame", "mozCancelAnimationFrame", "mozCancelRequestAnimationFrame", "scrollByLines", "scrollByPages", "sizeToContent", "updateCommands", "find", "dump", "setResizable", "btoa", "atob", "setTimeout", "clearTimeout", "setInterval", "clearInterval", "self", "name", "history", "locationbar", "menubar", "personalbar", "scrollbars", "statusbar", "toolbar", "status", "closed", "frames", "length", "opener", "parent", "frameElement", "navigator", "external", "applicationCache", "screen", "innerWidth", "innerHeight", "scrollX", "pageXOffset", "scrollY", "pageYOffset", "screenX", "screenY", "outerWidth", "outerHeight", "performance", "mozAnimationStartTime", "mozInnerScreenX", "mozInnerScreenY", "devicePixelRatio", "scrollMaxX", "scrollMaxY", "fullScreen", "mozPaintCount", "onwheel", "ondevicemotion", "ondeviceorientation", "ondeviceproximity", "onuserproximity", "ondevicelight", "content", "console", "sidebar", "crypto", "onabort", "onblur", "onfocus", "oncanplay", "oncanplaythrough", "onchange", "onclick", "oncontextmenu", "ondblclick", "ondrag", "ondragend", "ondragenter", "ondragleave", "ondragover", "ondragstart", "ondrop", "ondurationchange", "onemptied", "onended", "oninput", "oninvalid", "onkeydown", "onkeypress", "onkeyup", "onload", "onloadeddata", "onloadedmetadata", "onloadstart", "onmousedown", "onmouseenter", "onmouseleave", "onmousemove", "onmouseout", "onmouseover", "onmouseup", "onpause", "onplay", "onplaying", "onprogress", "onratechange", "onreset", "onresize", "onscroll", "onseeked", "onseeking", "onselect", "onshow", "onstalled", "onsubmit", "onsuspend", "ontimeupdate", "onvolumechange", "onwaiting", "onmozfullscreenchange", "onmozfullscreenerror", "onmozpointerlockchange", "onmozpointerlockerror", "indexedDB", "onerror", "onafterprint", "onbeforeprint", "onbeforeunload", "onhashchange", "onlanguagechange", "onmessage", "onoffline", "ononline", "onpagehide", "onpageshow", "onpopstate", "onunload", "localStorage", "sessionStorage", "window", "document", "location", "top", "$", "jQuery", "jQuery19107258252193071153", "obj", "virtualDirectory", "formatSizeUnits", "getThumb_folder", "getThumb_file", "getList_folder", "getList_file", "InstallTrigger"]
iframe["width"] <input id="width" class="input-small numbers-only" type="text" value="" title="Width" placeholder="Width">
```

As seen, "width" is not a key of iframe, and nor does Firebug show "width" when clicking `Window ~.php?task=get_image&dummy=1435083124957` in firebug.

Without randomly trying different strings such as "width", how can I determine the existing properties in a iframe element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Window.frames](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frames) && [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe), these are different, what you get is an `window.frame` object, which just like a sub window, you can use `innerWidth` to get its viewport's width. And if you use something like 
`document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];` you'll get a `<iFrame>` which is a dom element, so you can use something like `width` to access its properties like other dom elements.

I'm not sure which object you purposed to get, but it seems that if want to alter the `iframe`'s width, maybe you should use the `dom` one?

After some small tests, the `iframe['width']` will have value, will have 2 possible case:

1. Some js code in current domain assign value to `iframe['width']`
2. The iframe src pages' js assign value to its `window.width`

However both method both would make Object.keys(iframe) to have the key `width`.

So, some may do this

1. `Object.getPrototypeOf(iframe).width = .....;` in current window, or
2. `Object.getPrototypeOf(window).width = .....;` in iframe's src page.

I'm not sure why some will do this, but in that case, maybe you to access `Object.getPrototypeOf(iframe)` to get all possible keys.

Comment: But why does `iframe["width"]` return the `input`?

Comment: Are you sure its return `input`, I test and get `undefined` instead.

Comment: Yes, I am sure.  I realize you are going on limited info as you don't know if anything was applied to the iframe.  Regardless, I wouldn't expect `console.log('iframe["width"]',iframe["width"]);` to return the input.

Comment: I've finally got a link that able to use on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fLx85xkh/), I registered a click event on the div title, and I get undefined when accessing the `width`.